# Is latest by used here correctly

Tags: meaning

In the following sentence

[NASA’s International Space Station, the only one functional right now, is slated to retire by 2025, or **latest by 2028**, and no replacement for it has been confirmed so far.](https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/editorials/isro-space-station-mars-mission-mangalyaan-chandrayaan-vikram-sarabhai-a-home-in-space-5781467/)

I am not able to get the meaning of **latest by**

Comment: Check out the phrase "**at the** latest".

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, like Michael said, it would be better as "at the latest". It is only slightly incorrect but for something like a news article, it is wrong. Good catch!